# Corroded Neutral into Service Box

Tags: electrical

I live in a mobile home park. Just recently I turned on my garbage disposal and the crackling of electricity made me rush to turn it off. I noticed smoke down the hall in my laundry.....my dryer exhaust vent had caught fire. The smell of burning wire was extreme. Management said it was the wiring in my walls. Everytime I tried to turn something on it would cause my overhead lights to brighten than blow. I got scared and left. 11 days later they fixed the corroded neutral. My question is because of the excessive uncontrolled electricity flowing through my trailer are the existing wires damaged? Some appliances only partially blew while other's got fried. Why?

Comment: How many breakers do you have? How old are they/trailer? You should read the labels on each electrical item you have add it, and do not exceed about 3/4 of a breaker rating for any 1 circuit. Your dryer vent catching fire shouldn't be because of wire (presumably lint). Vents need to be cleaned out regularly. Regarding a corroded neutral, is water getting into the panel? If wires in your wall burned, and they were not replaced then there still may be a hazard. It should be tested by a professional electrician, and any sources of water removed, breakers tightened, and lint clear, be safe

Comment: The dryer vent was clean. The fire actually started when the exhaust vent touches the metal plate that exits the house. The wire was corroded and when I turned on my disposal there was no return path for the unbalanced load to go. And I'm assuming my exhaust vent was the path of least resistance. As it was being looked at to determine the fault a few breakers were replaced , but when power was restored it was blowing all my overhead bulbs. My lights were surging so bright it was unbelievable , than dim and than blow. The smell of burning wire in my home was frightening. Are existing wires safe

Answer (score 2):

This is a short question for a long answer. I am going to assume that you live in a mobile home or manufactured housing unit that has aluminum wiring in it. And what you are experiencing is the eventual deterioration of that type of system.

You need to inspect and repair all of the wiring termination, starting from you panel and continue all the way to your last outlet. If you do not feel you have the experience to complete the task yourself I would advise you find a trusted contractor and employee them to do it.

I am sorry to deliver the bad news but your situation requires immediate inspection and repair to prevent further damage to your system. It may be at an expense you were not prepared but I feel it must be dealt with.

Sorry to deliver the bad news. I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your honesty. I am not qualified nor do I feel comfortable trying to even attempt such a repair. I will do as you advise. Thank you